# How to debug protobuf-net missing types?

Tags: protobuf-net

I have over 100 classes that inherit from a generic base.  Therefore, I'm adding them dynamically at runtime using code like this:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(BaseClass<SubClass>),true)
    .AddSubType(1,typeof(SubClass));
```

Now I'm getting a "missing type" exception during serialization of a subclass, but I need to know which type it was trying to decipher.

Is there an event handler or something I can use?  How to determine the problem type?

Comment: Can you give the exact error message? I thought in most cases it did give the type...?

Comment: You are right.  I thought the error was buried in the callstack, but it was actually telling me the type that was missing.

Comment: @John, if Marc's answer fixed it for you, give him the accept.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: look at the exception; in most cases,  the `.Message` will tell you what exactly has upset it; if it doesn't say much, look also at the `.InnerException`, and so on. If, for some defined scenario, it still doesn't tell you anything useful: let me know ;p